# How do I make a responsive webpage?

Tags: css, cloud, html, responsive

I'm a novice programmer, only took one course in high school. I'm trying to make a website for my business, using c9.io to write- but can't figure out how to make my page adjust to any size. I've tried finding a solution online but can't seem to fix my problem- I'm completely stumped! Good luck and thanks!

HTML and CSS code below.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wl1Ui-vvB39ysCQd2B5-7Yl-gYRPdQ7hUyD_L-tDcs4/edit

Edit:

The problem has been fixed, here is the CSS code that I used:

```
.container4 {
  width:99%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This questions seems very broad. People have written books on how to make pages adapt to different sizes. Can you try to make your question more specific.

Comment: As I said i'm a novice programmer, I don't have much skill. I'm looking for a solution to make a responsive webpage work in my code, as previous attempts have not work. I don't know if If it's because I don't have that firm of an understanding just yet or if it's because I messed up my coding.

Answer (score 0):

[Media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) alongwith [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) are used to make websites responsive.

Media queries help you manage layouts for different devices say phones, tabs and desktop. Keep following in mind while writing css:-

1. Use ems/rems for margins/padding, avoid using pixels

   2.use sass instead of pure css, its really easy to scale